# MySQL-How to select column based on value in a different column but same row?

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to fetch a user id based on username from one of my tables using MySQL.
My table looks something like this:

```
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
|user_id|user_name|password|admin_role|
|-------+---------+--------+----------+
|1      |UserA    |passwd  |1         |
|2      |UserB    |passwd  |0         |
|3      |UserC    |passwd  |0         |
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
```

What kind of query would I have to make in order to select, for example, the number 1 from user_id after knowing the user_name, UserA? I am relatively new to SQL and have searched without finding anything.

The answer to my query would look something like this:

```
+-------+
|user_id|
+-------+
|1      |
+-------+
```

Comment: What is obvious to you is not obvious to me. I have looked up tutorials and examples already. Can you or someone link a tutorial to me that explains how to do this?

Comment: [so] is not a tutoring service, you're expected to learn the basics on your own. In SQL, you use `SELECT <columns>` to state which columns you want to return, and `WHERE <conditions>` to specify which rows you want to use. That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: The SQL query is almost the same as the English language in your first sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the simplest types of SQL queries.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM yourTable
WHERE user_name = 'UserA'
```

The first line says which columns you want to return in the result.

The second line identifies the table you want to get the columns from.

The third line specifies conditions on the rows you want to use from the table.